# Error when uploading multiple files in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a song uploading function using Axios in order to send the data to my server.

The backend requires audio file, image file and name for a single track.
So now, if I input an image file, react can recognize that image, but then I input an audio file, It throws me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Here is my code:

```
export default class Uploader2 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audio: null,
      image: null,
      name: ""
    };
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.fileUpload(this.state.audio, this.state.image, this.state.name).then(
      response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
    );
  }

  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      audio: e.target.files[0],
      image: e.target.files[1],
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }

  fileUpload(audio, image, name) {
    const url = "https://xxxx.xx.xxx/api/songs";
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("audio", audio);
    formData.append("image", image);
    formData.append("name", name);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "Bearer xxxxxxx"
      }
    };
    return axios.post(url, formData, config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <input
          type="file"
          name="audioUpload"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          multiple
        />
        <input type="file" name="imageUpload" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tested this feature with postman and It worked fine, so the bug must be in this code. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is being thrown in that line:

```
e.target.files[0]
```

It's because e.target.files can be null - for instance, if you open the select file window and click cancel.
I suggest you to check against null value and not to setState if there is no files selected:

```
onChangeHandler(e) {
  if(!e.target.files) {
    return;
  }

    this.setState({
      audio: e.target.files[0],
      image: e.target.files[1],
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but a new error occured, the image in the current state is still undefined  and we are just changing the audio and name property, the audio property is carrying file object (whether a audio or image file), and the name property is carrying the file's source path.

Comment: I suggest you split image and audio upload as it's unintuitive. So create separate upload for both of them - it will be easier for you to handle the changes. As for the `name` property - what value should that be?

Comment: You are right, I want to create a reusable code but It didn't work. Thanks for your suggestion.